# How to unit test void methods?

Tags: java, unit-testing

I have a method like this:

```
public void processEvent(Event e) {
   save(e); // void method
   broadcast(e); // void method.
}
```

However i changed it to filter certain events i dont want to broadcast:

```
public void processEvent(Event e) {
   save(e);
   if (e != "foo") {
      broadcast(e); 
   }  
}
```

How to unit test this change ?

Comment: If you are using a Mocking Framework like `Mockito` or something similar then you can just verify the times the `save()` and `broadcast()` methods have been invoked.

Comment: You have to check the side effects of the method: what do `save` and `broadcast` do that you can detect?

Comment: if you mean testing the condition, extract that into a meaningfully named function, then test that function. so if(isNotFoo(e)) or whatever

Comment: BTW although I'm sure it's just what you wrote for an example, `if (e != "foo") {` isn't going to compile.

Answer (score 2):

UnitTests verify *public observable behavior*, not "code".

Therefore you should verify the interaction of your "Class under Test" (cut) with its dependencies. This means: you check that your cut calls expected methods on the dependencies (or not).

One of this dependencies is the `Event` object.

Most likely the methods `save()` and `broadcast()` interact with other dependencies (objects of other classes).

Create mocks for all dependencies involved. Use a *mocking framework* like Mockito, JMock or alike.

Maybe you have to improve your class to create "seams", places where you can exchange the real objects with the mocks at test execution time. This is best done by *dependency injection*.

Then you can verify that you cut interacts with its dependencies as expected.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly your method should broadcast only certain Events.

You can verify how many times certain methods (broadcasts) have been executed.

I have used Mockito as a mocking framework and with it it looks something like this:

```
Mockito.verify(myEvent, times(1)).proccessEvent();
```

Where you will have to mock individual Events beforehand:

```
MyEvent myEvent = mock(myEvent.class);
```

Also if you want to check if the broadcast was not executed I recommend :

```
Mockito.verify(MyEvent, times(0)).proccessEvent();
```

Comment: This is close. You want to pas your instance (`myEvent`, not `MyEvent`) to `verify` and you will want to make sure your mock calls the real `processEvent` method, or nothing will ever be called.

Comment: Also, Mockito has the static import `never()` that can be used in place of `times(0)`.

Comment: Don't forget @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class) at the top of your Unit test and another tip is to mock objects faster using the @Mock annotation

Comment: True Adam ... I was hasty